# Suggest optimized query using 4 tables ( RIGHT JOIN v/s INNER JOIN & HAVING )

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have following table structure

- table_country ==> country_id (PK) | country | status
- table_department ==> department_id (PK) | department | country_id (FK)
- table_province ==> province_id (PK) | province | department_id (FK)
- table_district ==> district_id (PK) | district | province_id (FK)

NOTE: all tables engine  are innoDB

One country can have multiple department, one department can have multiple province and one province can have multiple district. Now I need to search only those country which have at least one district

I have written the below 2 SQL queries, in my case, both queries return the same results.... please describe the difference between those queries

Using a `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.country_id as id, c.country as name 
FROM table_country c 
RIGHT JOIN table_department d ON d.country_id=c.country_id 
RIGHT JOIN  table_province p ON p.department_id=d.department_id 
RIGHT JOIN table_district ds ON ds.province_id=p.province_id 
WHERE c.status='Active' GROUP BY (c.country_id)
```

Using `INNER JOIN` and `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(ds.district), c.country_id as id, c.country as name 
FROM table_country c 
INNER JOIN table_department d ON d.country_id = c.country_id 
INNER JOIN table_province p ON p.department_id = d.department_id 
INNER JOIN table_district ds ON ds.province_id = p.province_id 
WHERE c.status='Active' 
GROUP BY (c.country_id)  
HAVING  COUNT(ds.district)>0
```

Please tell me where these both query make the difference in results and which one I have to use or do I have to use a different query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The second query seems to be missing a `GROUP BY country_id,country`. The INNER JOIN makes the `HAVING` redundant.

Comment: @pascal AFAIK In inner join we will get matching records only where right or left join gives you null records as well.

Comment: @pascal what redundancy occur of using INNER JOIN & HAVING together, suggest some example

Comment: e.g. considering the first `INNER JOIN`, it will only return country containing (at least) a department, so department is not null. The same goes recursively for the others [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join), so country is not null. A `LEFT JOIN` (or a `CROSS JOIN`) could return country without matching department, leaving a null department.

Comment: The RIGHT JOIN of the first query would allow department without matching contry. But this is countered by the `c.status='Active'` predicate which filters out (at least) null contry.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the second of your 2 queries (with inner joins), but without the HAVING clause as it isn't required because the inner joins require that any row in the final result MUST have a row in the district table.

The first of your queries, using a more exotic series of RIGHT OUTER JOINS, ultimately produces the same outcome - but because they are outer joins it is potentially less efficient. Another way of representing your first query would be to reverse the table sequence like this:

```
SELECT
      c.country_id AS id
    , c.country AS name
    , COUNT(ds.district)
FROM table_district ds
      INNER JOIN table_province p ON ds.province_id = p.province_id
      INNER JOIN table_department d ON p.department_id = d.department_id
      INNER JOIN table_country c ON d.country_id = c.country_id
WHERE c.status='Active'
GROUP BY
      c.country_id
    , c.country
```

and hopefully when inverted like that it is clear that no result row can exist unless there is a row from the district table.